# My woocommerce before shop loop hook is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have edited my `function.php` file to contain the following code.
However on my shop page it is not showing up at all. I tried increasing the number from 12 to 40, but no difference. I also show my `product-archive.php` file below. I tried using a `do_action(etc etc)`, but it breaks since the `do_action` runs in the `product-archive.php`.

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );

function add_google_script(){
    echo "HELLO HELLO HELLO";
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_google_script', 12);
```

//If my product-archive.php

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */

    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
```

Comment: Add any hook modifications in your functions.php not in the template itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you want to achieve. But this snippet should add the content before the product loop:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_google_script', 12 );
function add_google_script(){
    if (is_product_category()) :
        echo "HELLO HELLO HELLO";
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this action, it will work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 10, 2 );
```